# C# SignalR alternative with support for Android and iOS

Tags: c#, websocket

I'm working on a project that needs to send messages from a server to clients with support for both Android and iOS. For now i'm using SignalR in a C# server application with Android and iOS clients. Everything is working fine. But i'm looking for some alternatives that may be better.

I also did some research and found some examples, but there not fitting my needs.

- [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket) (only iOS)
- [Alchemy Websocket](http://alchemywebsockets.net/) (not sure if supports native iOS and Android)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but in case this topic is still relevant to someone:

We have been using HTTP based requests from client to server and [Google Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) to push messages from our backend to a Xamarin iOS application (server to client) at work.

Firebase allows to:

> Send notification messages that are displayed to your user. Or send data messages and determine completely what happens in your application code.

and

> Add message handling, topic subscription logic, or other optional features to your client app. [...]

We mainly chose Firebase over SignalR because SignalR seemed to stop working when the application was running in the background and the managed C# threads were suspended by iOS.
Firebase turned out to be more reliable in these cases (at least in our use-case).
Although I have no experience with it, Firebase is also available on Android (it's a project by Google after all, so it is officially supported).

Saying either one being "generally better" than the other would come down to opinions and would have to be decided based on specific project requirements, but Firebase is a valid and mature alternative to SignalR in some circumstances, even though the integration with the iOS simulator does not seem to work (server side message push just fails with an exception, at least in our project).